# How to abort an update operation with beforeUpdate Hook Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can i abort an update operation using beforeUpdate hook on sequelize and return a object as the result from a aborted update,

if i have something like:

```
User.beforeUpdate(function(user, options) {
  if (user.name == "example_name") {
  // abort operation here 
  // return object to the update caller
  }
}
```

Comment: A fundamental question, I need the answer as well.

Comment: @QaisBsharat after a while i gave up on finding the solution to this using sequelize, i created a trigger on the database that solved my need

Answer (score 1):

**`throw` from before hooks does prevent the update**

E.g.:

```
  beforeUpdate: (integerName, options) => {
    if (integerName.value === 5) {
      throw new Error('beforeUpdate')
    }
  },
```

and throws on `.update` caller.

But remember from [why sequelize beforeUpdate hook doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412802/why-sequelize-beforeupdate-hook-doesnt-work/70554600#70554600) that the before only fires if the caller uses:

```
Model.update({}, {individualHooks: true})
```

which would be annoying to remember to pass every time.

The `beforeValidate` hook however fires even without `individualHooks`, so maybe that's the way to go.

The fact that throwing works for create is documented at: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#instance-hooks

> ```
> User.beforeCreate(user => {
>   if (user.accessLevel > 10 && user.username !== "Boss") {
>     throw new Error("You can't grant this user an access level above 10!");
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> The following example will throw an error:
>
> ```
> try {
>   await User.create({ username: 'Not a Boss', accessLevel: 20 });
> } catch (error) {
>   console.log(error); // You can't grant this user an access level above 10!
> };
> ```
>
> The following example will be successful:
>
> ```
> const user = await User.create({ username: 'Boss', accessLevel: 20 });
> console.log(user); // user object with username 'Boss' and accessLevel of 20
> ```

Also mentioned at: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11298

Minimal runnable example:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
  })
}
function assertEqual(rows, rowsExpect) {
  assert.strictEqual(rows.length, rowsExpect.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i]
    let rowExpect = rowsExpect[i]
    for (let key in rowExpect) {
      assert.strictEqual(row[key], rowExpect[key])
    }
  }
}
;(async () => {
const IntegerNames = sequelize.define('IntegerNames',
  {
    value: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (integerName, options) => {
        if (integerName.value === 42) {
          throw new Error('beforeCreate')
        }
      },
      beforeValidate: (integerName, options) => {
        if (integerName.value === 43) {
          throw new Error('beforeValidate')
        }
      },
      beforeUpdate: (integerName, options) => {
        if (integerName.value === 5) {
          throw new Error('beforeUpdate')
        }
      },
    }
  },
)
await IntegerNames.sync({ force: true })
async function reset() {
  await sequelize.truncate({ cascade: true })
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 2, name: 'two' })
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 3, name: 'three' })
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 5, name: 'five' })
}
async function assertUnchanged() {
  const rows = await IntegerNames.findAll()
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'two',   },
    { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'three', },
    { id: 3, value: 5, name: 'five',  },
  ])
}
await reset()
let rows, exc
await assertUnchanged()

// beforeCreate
exc = undefined
try {
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 42, name: 'forty-two' })
} catch (e) {
  exc = e
}
assert.strictEqual(exc.message, 'beforeCreate')
await assertUnchanged()

// beforeValidate
exc = undefined
try {
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 43, name: 'forty-three' })
} catch (e) {
  exc = e
}
assert.strictEqual(exc.message, 'beforeValidate')
await assertUnchanged()

// beforeUpdate
exc = undefined
try {
  await IntegerNames.update(
    { name: 'five hacked', },
    {
      where: { value: 5 },
      individualHooks: true,
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  exc = e
}
assert.strictEqual(exc.message, 'beforeUpdate')
await assertUnchanged()

// using the beforeValidate
exc = undefined
try {
  await IntegerNames.update(
    { value: 43, },
    {
      where: { value: 5 },
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  exc = e
}
assert.strictEqual(exc.message, 'beforeValidate')
await assertUnchanged()
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() })
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.14.0",
    "sql-formatter": "4.0.2",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/2c93663b85f117b4ead83160bb13e1310b4a7c0e/nodejs/sequelize/hook_abort.js). Tested on Ubuntu 21.10, PostgreSQL 13.5.