# why sequelize beforeUpdate hook doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-hooks

I have a simple user model with 2 hooks.

```
User.beforeCreate(setSaltAndPass)
User.beforeUpdate(setSaltAndPass)
```

the first works perfectly but the beforeUpdate does not run, according to the documentation you should have no problem executing the following

```
await User.update(user, {
             where: {
               id
             }

         })
```

is saving the key as plain text, it does not happen for example with the create. Curiously beforeBulkUpdate is executed when it is updated.

this is the callback, the detail is that in bulk I don't have the changed property or at least I don't know how to access it.

```
const setSaltAndPass = user => {
   if (user.changed('pass')) {
     user.salt = User.generateSalt()
     user.pass = User.encriptPass(user.pass(), user.salt())
   }
}
```

does its job, but hook its not excecuted.

Comment: same problem, I can't access the instances on beforeBulkUpdate? Does anyone has an answer? @Niko Mol's answer below is a good workaround, but what if I really want to use that Model.update and access the instances? I don't like the `individualHooks` workaround as sequelize says that it can cause performance issues

Answer (score 12):

Set `individualHooks: true,` in the options block

```
await User.update(user, {
  where: {
    id
  },
    individualHooks: true,
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `individualHooks` to `true` in update function,
please see the below example

```
const [, [user]] = await User.update(body, {
      where,
      returning: true,
      attributes: ['userId', 'email'],
      individualHooks: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in TS just now. Turn out, that the `@BeforeUpdate` hook is triggered, when you first find a single record and then update it:

```ts
await Model.findOne(options).then((result) => { 
    result.update(options); 
});
```

In case you prefer the `Model.update(...)` approach, you can use the `@BeforeBulkUpdate` hook instead.

Found this info here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6253

This worked for me, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If using classes, you could override the Model method as follows:

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

class MyModel extends Model {
  static async update(values, options) {
    // Maybe custom logic here... 
    return super.update(values, { ...options, individualHooks: true });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use beforeBulkUpdate instead on beforeUpdate

Comment: Great ! totally logic , update is for bulk updates , check this doc link :
https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/querying/update/#updating-in-bulk